# How do I specify a specific commit when manually running git action?

Tags: github-actions, workflow

How do I create a workflow that can only be started manually, while it will need to specify a specific commit with which it will work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [manually run a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow), provided it is configured  to run on the [`workflow_dispatch` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch).
Add [`inputs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context) to define your parameter

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      myCommit:
        description: 'Commit SHA1'
        required: true
        default: 'undefined'
        type: string

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Do something
        run: your_command ${{ inputs.myCommit }}
  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example how to check out the specific commit for build:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      refToBuild:
        description: 'Branch, tag or commit SHA1 to build'
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ inputs.refToBuild }}

      - name: Build
        run: <command for build>
```